# Google cloud KMS permission issue with encrypt

Tags: php, google-cloud-kms

I tried to encrypt the contents of a file and to write the encrypted data to a cipher file with Google cloud KMS. But the php script shows a permission error. Here's the php script I tried

```
$cryptoKeyName = $kms->cryptoKeyName($projectId, $locationId, $keyRingId, $cryptoKeyId);
$plaintext = file_get_contents($plaintextFileName);

$response = $kms->encrypt($cryptoKeyName, $plaintext);
file_put_contents($ciphertextFileName, $response->getCiphertext());
```

I got this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ApiException: { "message": "Permission 'cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToEncrypt' denied for resource 'projects/testproject/locations/global/keyRings/test/cryptoKeys/testkey'.", "code": 7, "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [] } thrown in /home/xxxxx/xxx.com/vendor/google/gax/src/ApiException.php on line 139

When I print the user permission, it shows

```
Role: roles/cloudkms.admin Members: user:renjith@pi-digi.com Role: roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter Members: user:renjith@pi-digi.com`
```

Comment: From where are you running this command? How have you authenticated? How did you print the users permissions?

Comment: Now I am testing the script from a test domain. To get authentication, I downloaded and included a json file containing a private key from https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?project=xxxx . I used this script to display permission - $kms = new KeyManagementServiceClient();
$keyRingName = $kms->keyRingName($projectId, $locationId, $keyRingId);
$keyRingPolicy = $kms->getIamPolicy($keyRingName);

Comment: Where did you put the service account? From where are you running this code?

Comment: Hi sethvargo, sorry I didn't get what you mean by the service account. You mean the google account? If so it is renjith@pi-digi.com; the one shown in above comment. Running this code from a test domain as php file.

Comment: Solved the issue. I was a permission issue with the json file I used to authenticate. The file should have enough permission. I had given Owner permission. You can see the file here - https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/

Answer (score 3):

The Cloud KMS Admin role does not include the Encrypt/Decrypt permission.  You'll need to grant those permissions to your user as well.

Comment: The output includes `Role: roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter Members: user:renjith@pi-digi.com`, which makes me think that the user was granted those permissions though. I'm thinking it's more likely that DAC or the wrong service account is being used.

Comment: sethvargo, what you mean by DAC?

Comment: Default Application Credentials - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032678/where-are-google-application-default-credentials-stored

Comment: @Renjith - In Google Cloud we call this ADC (Application Default Credentials). DAC has a different meaning (Discretionary Access Control).

Answer (score -1):

Solved the issue. It was a permission issue with the json file I used to authenticate (Something like projectname-bab93421213c2.json). The file should have enough permission. You can see the file here - console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin. I changed the permission from 'Viewer' to 'Owner' and it worked.

Comment: I strongly recommend against giving Owner permissions to a service account. Anyone with access to that JSON file can act as a full owner of your project. You should give that service account only the permissions it needs e.g.`roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter`

Comment: Thanks sethvargo. I changed the permission to Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter and it works.

Comment: @Renjith, to resolve permission issue, you added role as "Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter" to your email(renjith@pi-digi.com) or service account?

Comment: Hi  user6016913, in the service account

Comment: @Renjith, Thanks. But it returns same error. I added "Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter" role in the **Cryptographic keys** page. Is that correct?

Comment: Not in Cryptographic keys page. It's in IAM page where you can add and set the permission to service account